# developers.google.com 配下のドキュメントに常に英語でアクセスする方法

Tags: untagged

developers.google.com 配下にあるドキュメントは
Googleのアカウントの標準の言語設定によって自動的に切り替えられるようなのですが、
英語版以外は情報が古いことがままあるため標準で英語版を表示するようにしたいです。

Googleの使用自体は日本語でしたいのですが、開発関係のURLの場合のみ英語版で取り扱うといったことは可能でしょうか？

一応URL末尾に`?hl=en`をつけて手動で英語に切り替えれますし、
同様の操作をなんらかのブラウザのプラグインで行うことはできるでしょうが
できればGoogleの設定から行いたいと思っています。

Comment: ブラウザの言語設定で「英語」にするのじゃダメですかね。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

当該サイトのフッターに言語選択のボックスがありますが、これを切り替えると `django_language` Cookieに選択した言語がセットされるため（ブラウザを閉じるまでは）その言語設定がキープされるのではないでしょうか。

[image]

そしてこれはDjangoの機能のようなのでこれに任意期間のCookieを入れておいても永続化はできそうな気がします。

試しにブラウザのコンソールに以下のコードを入力してリロードしてみましょう。

```
document.cookie='django_language=en; path=/; expires=Sat, 31 Dec 2022 00:00:00 GMT; '
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。言語切替のフッターに気づいていませんでした。Cookieの方法も勉強になりました。